# One LiveData returns null

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata, android-architecture-components

I have been trying to combine two livedata to show on one activity.
I have table Item, ItemMoto and ItemFavourite. When a product is added to the favorite from products that were stored inside Item or ItemMoto it safes id, itemi, ...

I used this library [livedata-combineutil-java](https://github.com/Zhuinden/livedata-combineutil-java/blob/master/livedata-combineutil-java/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/livedatacombineutiljava/LiveDataCombineUtil.java) to combine results from Item and ItemMoto. I have tried to combine them from View Module, but I was not not getting results. Here is how I did it from Fragment.

```
        LiveData<Pair<Resource<List<Item>>, Resource<List<ItemMoto>>>> news =
     combine(favouriteViewModel.getItemFavouriteData(), favouriteViewModelMoto.getItemFavouriteData(),
            (favorite, favoriteMoto) -> { 
         return Pair.create(favorite, favoriteMoto);
            });

    if (news != null) {
        news.observe(this, listResource -> {
            if (listResource != null) {

                switch (listResource.first.status) {
                    case LOADING:
                        // Loading State
                        // Data are from Local DB
                        if (listResource.first.data != null) {
                            //fadeIn Animation
                            fadeIn(binding.get().getRoot());
                            // Update the data
                            replaceDataItems(listResource.first.data, listResource.second.data);
                        }
                        break;
                    case SUCCESS:
                        // Success State
                        // Data are from Server
                        if (listResource.first.data != null) {
                            // Update the data
                            replaceDataItems(listResource.first.data, listResource.second.data);
                        }
                        favouriteViewModel.setLoadingState(false);

                        break;
                    case ERROR:
                        // Error State
                        favouriteViewModel.setLoadingState(false);
                        break;
                    default:
                        // Default
                        break;
                }
            } else {

                // Init Object or Empty Data

                if (favouriteViewModel.offset > 1) {
                    // No more data for this list
                    // So, Block all future loading
                    favouriteViewModel.forceEndLoading = true;
                }

            }

        });
    }
```

when I check for :

```
 Log.d("favourite moto live", favouriteViewModelMoto.getItemFavouriteData().toString());
 
 Log.d("favourite  live", favouriteViewModel.getItemFavouriteData().toString());
```

am getting results, but `listResource.second.data` is returning null.

Here is a link to the Resource file:

https://pastebin.com/ZGtBzLV0

***Update:***

Originally, Item and ItemMoto have their own Activity and Fragment along with their own LiveData.
I am retrieving data using ROOM and PHP from server.

For Item:

```
  @Query("SELECT prd.* FROM Item prd, ItemFavourite fp WHERE prd.id = 
  fp.itemId order by fp.sorting ")
   LiveData<List<Item>> getAllFavouriteProducts();
```

For ItemMoto:

```
  @Query("SELECT prd.* FROM ItemMoto prd, ItemFavourite fp WHERE prd.id =  
  fp.itemId order by fp.sorting ")
   LiveData<List<ItemMoto>> getAllFavouriteProducts();
```

ViewModel

```
package com.panaceasoft.psbuyandsell.viewmodel.item;

import android.util.Log;
import androidx.core.util.Pair;
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.Transformations;

import com.panaceasoft.psbuyandsell.Config;
import com.panaceasoft.psbuyandsell.repository.item.ItemMotoRepository;
import com.panaceasoft.psbuyandsell.repository.item.ItemRepository;
import com.panaceasoft.psbuyandsell.utils.AbsentLiveData;
import com.panaceasoft.psbuyandsell.utils.Utils;
import com.panaceasoft.psbuyandsell.viewmodel.common.PSViewModel;
import com.panaceasoft.psbuyandsell.viewobject.Item;
import com.panaceasoft.psbuyandsell.viewobject.ItemMoto;
 import com.panaceasoft.psbuyandsell.viewobject.common.Resource;

import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import static   
com.zhuinden.livedatacombineutiljava.LiveDataCombineUtil.combine;

public class FavouriteViewModel extends PSViewModel {
private final LiveData<Resource<Boolean>> sendFavouritePostData;


private MutableLiveData<FavouriteViewModel.TmpDataHolder> 
sendFavouriteDataPostObj = new MutableLiveData<>();
private LiveData<Resource<List<Item>>> itemFavouriteData;
private LiveData<Resource<List<ItemMoto>>> itemFavouriteDataMoto;
private MutableLiveData<FavouriteViewModel.TmpDataHolder>  
itemFavouriteListObj = new MutableLiveData<>();
private MutableLiveData<FavouriteMotoViewModel.TmpDataHolder> 
itemFavouriteListObjMoto = new MutableLiveData<>();

private final LiveData<Resource<Boolean>> nextPageFavouriteLoadingData;
private MutableLiveData<FavouriteViewModel.TmpDataHolder> nextPageLoadingFavouriteObj = new MutableLiveData<>();

@Inject
FavouriteViewModel(ItemRepository itemRepository, ItemMotoRepository itemMotoRepository) {


    sendFavouritePostData = Transformations.switchMap(sendFavouriteDataPostObj, obj -> {

        if (obj == null) {
            return AbsentLiveData.create();
        }
        return itemRepository.uploadFavouritePostToServer(obj.itemId, obj.userId);
    });

    itemFavouriteData = Transformations.switchMap(itemFavouriteListObj, obj -> {
        if (obj == null) {
            return AbsentLiveData.create();
        }
        Utils.psLog("itemFavouriteData");
        return itemRepository.getFavouriteList(Config.API_KEY, obj.userId, obj.offset);
    });

 //Moto
    itemFavouriteDataMoto = 
 Transformations.switchMap(itemFavouriteListObjMoto, obj -> {
        if (obj == null) {
            return AbsentLiveData.create();
        }
        Utils.psLog("itemFavouriteData");
        return itemMotoRepository.getFavouriteList(Config.API_KEY,  
  obj.userId, obj.offset);
    });

    nextPageFavouriteLoadingData = Transformations.switchMap(nextPageLoadingFavouriteObj, obj -> {
        if (obj == null) {
            return AbsentLiveData.create();
        }
        Utils.psLog("nextPageFavouriteLoadingData");
        return itemRepository.getNextPageFavouriteProductList(obj.userId, obj.offset);
    });

}

///
public void setFavouritePostDataObj(String itemId, String userId) {

    if (!isLoading) {
        FavouriteViewModel.TmpDataHolder tmpDataHolder = new FavouriteViewModel.TmpDataHolder();
        tmpDataHolder.itemId = itemId;
        tmpDataHolder.userId = userId;

        sendFavouriteDataPostObj.setValue(tmpDataHolder);
        setLoadingState(true);
    }

}

//region Getter And Setter for item detail List
public void setItemFavouriteListObj(String loginUserId, String offset) {
    if (!isLoading) {
        FavouriteViewModel.TmpDataHolder tmpDataHolder = new FavouriteViewModel.TmpDataHolder();
        tmpDataHolder.userId = loginUserId;
        tmpDataHolder.offset = offset;
        itemFavouriteListObj.setValue(tmpDataHolder);

        // start loading
        setLoadingState(true);
    }
}

public LiveData<Resource<List<Item>>> getItemFavouriteData() {

    return itemFavouriteData;
}

public LiveData<Resource<List<ItemMoto>>> getItemFavouriteDataMoto() {

    return itemFavouriteDataMoto;
}

public LiveData<Resource<Boolean>> getFavouritePostData() {
    return sendFavouritePostData;
}

class TmpDataHolder {
    public String itemId = "";
    public String userId = "";
    public String cityId = "";
    public String offset = "";
}
```

}

When I check for favourite products, I see products from Item. I refresh, then I see products from ItemMoto, but never together.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simple approch like a "3rd LiveData" for the Combined value?

```
MutableLiveData<ItemMoto> mMotoLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
MutableLiveData<ItemFavorite> mFavoriteLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
MutableLiveData<Pair<ItemMoto,ItemFavorite>> mCombinedLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
ItemMoto mLastItemMoto = null;
ItemFavorite mLastItemFavorite = null;
...
mMotoLiveData.observe(..., onChanged(@Nullable ItemMoto moto){
  mLastItemMoto = moto;
  mCombinedLiveData.postValue(new Pair<>(mLastItemMoto, mLastItemFavorite));
});
mFavoriteLiveData.observe(..., onChanged(@Nullable ItemFavorite favorite){
  mLastItemFavorite = favorite;
  mCombinedLiveData.postValue(new Pair<>(mLastItemMoto, mLastItemFavorite));
});
mCombinedLiveData.observe(..., onChanged(@NonNull Pair<ItemMoto,ItemFavorite> pair){
  //pair.one and/or pair.second could be NULL, so pay attention!!
});
```

Pay attention that LiveData "onChanged()" events are not triggered by ALL "postValue()" calls because if there are too much frequent of them only few (or the latest) will trigger their onChanged() event, so if you would like to get **ALL COMBINATIONS** of ItemMoto+ItemFavorite using LiveDatas could not be useful for you.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please take a look

Comment: I try to not use 3rd party libraries so my suggestion is based on my personal thought. Viewing library source code it seems (but I read it very quickly) it's similar to my solution by using a Mediator and each observe() on both initial LiveDatas. If you need to understand what is the problem put some Breakpoints and then go INTO the library to watch why NULL is returned. It's difficult to help users when they're using 3rd libraries not often used by most of the programmers.....